# I want to erase the error

Tags: equation-solving, warning-messages

Error message does not disappear.
I can not solve the same number of solve expression and variable.
Please tell me some advice.

```
Subscript[p, 0, 3], Subscript[p, 1, 2], Subscript[p, 1, 3], \
Subscript[p, 2, 1], Subscript[p, 2, 2], Subscript[p, 2, 3], \
Subscript[p, 3, 0], Subscript[p, 3, 1], Subscript[p, 3, 2], \
Subscript[p, 3, 3], Subscript[p, 4, 0], Subscript[p, 4, 1], \
Subscript[p, 4, 2], Subscript[p, 5, 0], Subscript[p, 5, 1], \
Subscript[p, 6, 0]
```

and

```
300 Subscript[p, 0, 3] == 30 Subscript[p, 1, 2] + 30 Subscript[p, 1, 3], 
330 Subscript[p, 1, 2] == 50 Subscript[p, 1, 3] + 30 Subscript[p, 2, 1] + 30 
Subscript[p, 2, 2], 
380 Subscript[p, 1, 3] == 300 Subscript[p, 0, 3] + 30 Subscript[p, 2, 3],
330 Subscript[p, 2, 1] == 50 Subscript[p, 2, 2] + 30 Subscript[p, 3, 0] + 30 
Subscript[p, 3, 1], 
380 Subscript[p, 2, 2] == 
300 Subscript[p, 1, 2] + 50 Subscript[p, 2, 3] + 30 Subscript[p, 3, 2],
380 Subscript[p, 2, 3] == 300 Subscript[p, 1, 3] + 30 Subscript[p, 3, 3], 
330 Subscript[p, 3, 0] == 50 Subscript[p, 3, 1] + 30 Subscript[p, 4, 0], 
380 Subscript[p, 3, 1] == 
300 Subscript[p, 2, 1] + 50 Subscript[p, 3, 2] + 30 Subscript[p, 4, 1], 
380 Subscript[p, 3, 2] == 
300 Subscript[p, 2, 2] + 50 Subscript[p, 3, 3] + 30 Subscript[p, 4, 2], 
80 Subscript[p, 3, 3] == 300 Subscript[p, 2, 3], 
330 Subscript[p, 4, 0] ==
300 Subscript[p, 3, 0] + 50 Subscript[p, 4, 1] + 30 Subscript[p, 5, 0],  
380 Subscript[p, 4, 1] == 
300 Subscript[p, 3, 1] + 50 Subscript[p, 4, 2] + 30 Subscript[p, 5, 1], 
80 Subscript[p, 4, 2] == 300 Subscript[p, 3, 2], 
330 Subscript[p, 5, 0] == 
300 Subscript[p, 4, 0] + 50 Subscript[p, 5, 1] + 30 Subscript[p, 6, 0], 
80 Subscript[p, 5, 1] == 300 Subscript[p, 4, 1], 
30 Subscript[p, 6, 0] == 300 Subscript[p, 5, 0]
```

I get an error when solved

Comment: what if you used variables like `p12` instead of `Subscript[p, 1, 2]`? (but other than this it really is not clear what you are asking)

Comment: Try to make braces (`{}`) around the comma seperated lists of equations...

Comment: TIP: don't use subscripts.

Comment: Try `// Quiet` if you merely want to "erase" an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is generally easier and safer to use indexed variables rather than subscripts. The indexed variables can be **displayed** as subscripts using [`Format`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Format.html).

```
Format[p[m_, n_]] := Subscript[p, m, n]

vars = {p[0, 3], p[1, 2], p[1, 3], p[2, 1], p[2, 2], p[2, 3], p[3, 0], 
   p[3, 1], p[3, 2], p[3, 3], p[4, 0], p[4, 1], p[4, 2], p[5, 0], p[5, 1], 
   p[6, 0]};

eqns = {
   300 p[0, 3] == 30 p[1, 2] + 30 p[1, 3],
   330 p[1, 2] == 50 p[1, 3] + 30 p[2, 1] + 30 p[2, 2],
   380 p[1, 3] == 300 p[0, 3] + 30 p[2, 3],
   330 p[2, 1] == 50 p[2, 2] + 30 p[3, 0] + 30 p[3, 1],
   380 p[2, 2] == 300 p[1, 2] + 50 p[2, 3] + 30 p[3, 2],
   380 p[2, 3] == 300 p[1, 3] + 30 p[3, 3],
   330 p[3, 0] == 50 p[3, 1] + 30 p[4, 0],
   380 p[3, 1] == 300 p[2, 1] + 50 p[3, 2] + 30 p[4, 1],
   380 p[3, 2] == 300 p[2, 2] + 50 p[3, 3] + 30 p[4, 2],
   80 p[3, 3] == 300 p[2, 3],
   330 p[4, 0] == 300 p[3, 0] + 50 p[4, 1] + 30 p[5, 0],
   380 p[4, 1] == 300 p[3, 1] + 50 p[4, 2] + 30 p[5, 1],
   80 p[4, 2] == 300 p[3, 2],
   330 p[5, 0] == 300 p[4, 0] + 50 p[5, 1] + 30 p[6, 0],
   80 p[5, 1] == 300 p[4, 1],
   30 p[6, 0] == 300 p[5, 0]};

sol1 = Solve[eqns, vars][[1]]
```

[image]

There are an infinite number of solutions since the value of `p[0, 3]` is arbitrary.  That is what the **warning** message is saying. Alternatively, you can select which variable is arbitrary.

```
vars[[pos = RandomInteger[{2, 16}]]]
```

[image]

Since only 15 of the variables are requested the **warning** message does not appear.

```
sol2 = Solve[eqns, Drop[vars, {pos}]][[1]]
```

[image]

Comment: ＠Bob Hanlon Thanks for the advice.I want to find all the values of 16 variables.

Comment: @KentaKawai - Only 15 of your equations are [`linearly independent`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence) so you can solve for 15 of the variables in terms of one of the others.

Comment: I understood the meaning. Do you know how to solve approximate values ​​here?

Comment: @KentaKawai - `sol1 // N`

Comment: Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

Paired **{}** should be used, so that:

```
{   Subscript[p, 0, 3], Subscript[p, 1, 2], Subscript[p, 1, 3], \
Subscript[p, 2, 1], Subscript[p, 2, 2], Subscript[p, 2, 3], \
Subscript[p, 3, 0], Subscript[p, 3, 1], Subscript[p, 3, 2], \
Subscript[p, 3, 3], Subscript[p, 4, 0], Subscript[p, 4, 1], \
Subscript[p, 4, 2], Subscript[p, 5, 0], Subscript[p, 5, 1], \
Subscript[p, 6, 0]   }
```

gives

$$\left\{p_{0,3},p_{1,2},p_{1,3},p_{2,1},p_{2,2},p_{2,3},p_{3,0},p_{3,1},p_{3,2},p_{3,
   3},p_{4,0},p_{4,1},p_{4,2},p_{5,0},p_{5,1},p_{6,0}\right\}$$

and

```
{

300 Subscript[p, 0, 3] == 30 Subscript[p, 1, 2] + 30 Subscript[p, 1, 3], 
330 Subscript[p, 1, 2] == 50 Subscript[p, 1, 3] + 30 Subscript[p, 2, 1] + 30 
Subscript[p, 2, 2], 
380 Subscript[p, 1, 3] == 300 Subscript[p, 0, 3] + 30 Subscript[p, 2, 3],
330 Subscript[p, 2, 1] == 50 Subscript[p, 2, 2] + 30 Subscript[p, 3, 0] + 30 
Subscript[p, 3, 1], 
380 Subscript[p, 2, 2] == 
300 Subscript[p, 1, 2] + 50 Subscript[p, 2, 3] + 30 Subscript[p, 3, 2],
380 Subscript[p, 2, 3] == 300 Subscript[p, 1, 3] + 30 Subscript[p, 3, 3], 
330 Subscript[p, 3, 0] == 50 Subscript[p, 3, 1] + 30 Subscript[p, 4, 0], 
380 Subscript[p, 3, 1] == 
300 Subscript[p, 2, 1] + 50 Subscript[p, 3, 2] + 30 Subscript[p, 4, 1], 
380 Subscript[p, 3, 2] == 
300 Subscript[p, 2, 2] + 50 Subscript[p, 3, 3] + 30 Subscript[p, 4, 2], 
80 Subscript[p, 3, 3] == 300 Subscript[p, 2, 3], 
330 Subscript[p, 4, 0] ==
300 Subscript[p, 3, 0] + 50 Subscript[p, 4, 1] + 30 Subscript[p, 5, 0],  
380 Subscript[p, 4, 1] == 
300 Subscript[p, 3, 1] + 50 Subscript[p, 4, 2] + 30 Subscript[p, 5, 1], 
80 Subscript[p, 4, 2] == 300 Subscript[p, 3, 2], 
330 Subscript[p, 5, 0] == 
300 Subscript[p, 4, 0] + 50 Subscript[p, 5, 1] + 30 Subscript[p, 6, 0], 
80 Subscript[p, 5, 1] == 300 Subscript[p, 4, 1], 
30 Subscript[p, 6, 0] == 300 Subscript[p, 5, 0]

}
```

gives

$$\left\{300 p_{0,3}=30 p_{1,2}+30 p_{1,3},330 p_{1,2}=50 p_{1,3}+30 p_{2,1}+30
   p_{2,2},380 p_{1,3}=300 p_{0,3}+30 p_{2,3},330 p_{2,1}=50 p_{2,2}+30 p_{3,0}+30
   p_{3,1},380 p_{2,2}=300 p_{1,2}+50 p_{2,3}+30 p_{3,2},380 p_{2,3}=300 p_{1,3}+30
   p_{3,3},330 p_{3,0}=50 p_{3,1}+30 p_{4,0},380 p_{3,1}=300 p_{2,1}+50 p_{3,2}+30
   p_{4,1},380 p_{3,2}=300 p_{2,2}+50 p_{3,3}+30 p_{4,2},80 p_{3,3}=300 p_{2,3},330
   p_{4,0}=300 p_{3,0}+50 p_{4,1}+30 p_{5,0},380 p_{4,1}=300 p_{3,1}+50 p_{4,2}+30
   p_{5,1},80 p_{4,2}=300 p_{3,2},330 p_{5,0}=300 p_{4,0}+50 p_{5,1}+30 p_{6,0},80
   p_{5,1}=300 p_{4,1},30 p_{6,0}=300 p_{5,0}\right\}$$